# C++ - No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, graphics, vertex

I am currently working on a college assignment and right now I'm struggling with vectors.

I am supposed to return a unique ID for an object and then add that object to a vector.

The object is a struct defined as follows:

```
struct VertexPuller{
    std::vector<InVertex> head_settings;
    std::vector<IndexType> indexing;
};
```

and the vector I am trying to push to is:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<VertexPuller>> vertex_puller_tables;
```

The function I wrote looks like this:

```
auto vertex_puller= std::make_unique<VertexPuller>;
auto vp_id = reinterpret_cast<VertexPullerID>(vertex_puller);

vertex_puller_tables.push_back(std::move(vertex_puller));

return vp_id;
```

However at the second-to-last line, when i try to push the vertex puller into the vector, I get the error - **No matching member function for call to 'push_back'**.

I've been stuck on this for quite some time and i have no idea what may cause this, probably pointers, as usual with C and me.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<VertexPullerID>(vertex_puller)` - What do you think this does? You're `reinterpret_cast`ing an `std::unique_ptr` to your `VertexPullerID` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertex_puller` is a `std::make_unique<VertexPuller>` function. It's not a `unique_ptr<VertexPuller>`. You have to call the function and pass any parameters you would pass to a `VertexPuller` constructor.

```
auto vertex_puller= std::make_unique<VertexPuller>(); // note the parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! What a stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for the other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The method `push_back` is there. The type that you send probably doesn't match. Try to read the compilation error and figure out what type was expected and what was the actual type that was sent.

A more simple example with same error:

```
int main()  {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back("hey");
}
```

Compilation error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to `push_back`
```

However, if we read further it says:

```
main.cpp:6:24: error: no matching function for call to 'push_back(const char [4])'
    6 |     vec.push_back("hey");
      |                        ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/vector:67,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1184:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int]' <near match>
 1184 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1184:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:6:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'std::vector<int>::value_type' {aka 'int'} [-fpermissive]
    6 |     vec.push_back("hey");
      |                   ^~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   const char*
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/vector:67,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1200:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = int]' <near match>
 1200 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1200:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cpp:6:19: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'std::vector<int>::value_type' {aka 'int'} [-fpermissive]
    6 |     vec.push_back("hey");
      |                   ^~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   const char*
```

Answer (score -1):

[No matching function for call to 'push_back' ans.push_back(output)][1]

Line 7: Char 13: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
ans.push_back(output);
~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1184:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const std::vectorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::allocatorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>::value_type' (aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string') for 1st argument
push_back(const value_type& __x)
^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1200:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'std::vectorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::allocatorstd::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>::value_type' (aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string') for 1st argument
push_back(value_type&& __x)
^
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igqui.png

this is due to because pass the output  as a int  in the function call and i declare this as a string .